# Cambiar el font-size de un h1

Tags: html, css, font-size

Tengo un problema que no puedo resolver. Tengo un código en el que tengo un h1 el cual no puedo cambiar de tamaño y no entiendo por que. Puedo cambiar el tamaño del h2 y del p pero no del h1. Lo e cambiado de lugar y nada.¿Alguien puedoe ayudarme?
Aqui os dejo el codigo.. Tiene imágenes y sin las imágenes la estructura cambia.. pero no se como insrtarlas para que las veais aqui.. si tambien me podeis ayudar con eso. Si no se pueden insertar imágenes en el cpodigo de la pregunta, cambio el código enseguida para poder ver bien el resultado.

```css
body{
 font-size: 16px; 
 background-color: white;
}
img{
 width: 100%;
}
figure{ 
 position: relative;
 width:100%; 
 margin:auto;
}
#mierda{
 z-index:-20;
 position:relative;
 background-color: #ccc;
 width:100%;
 height:1000px;
 margin:auto;
}
#masmierda{
 position: relative;
 width:100%;
 margin:auto;
}

#muchamasmierda{
 margin:auto;
 background-color: #ccc;
 width:100%;
 height:200px;
}

p{ 
 padding-top:10px;
 margin:auto;
 width:70%; 
 font-size:12px;
}

p:first-child{
 padding-top:50px;
}

#jodo{
 margin:auto;
 background-color: green;
 top:-10px;
 z-index:-10; 
}

.fachada{
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 2px 10px black);
}

h1{
 color:white;
 position:fixed;
 text-align: center;
 font-size:10px;
 right:0;
 left:0; 
}

h2{
 position:relative;
 bottom:-47px;
 margin-left:10px;
 font-size:20px; 
 z-index:30;

}

.fachada-p{
 position: fixed;
 top:0;
 filter: drop-shadow(0px 2px 10px black);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>cunt</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="cunt.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
 <script> src="modernizr-custom.js"</script>
</head>
<body>
 
 <section id="mierda">
  <figure id="masmierda">
   <a href="https://placeholder.com/"><img class="fachada-p" src="https://via.placeholder.com/550x65

C/O https://placeholder.com/ " alt=""></a>
  </figure>
  <h1>POSADA </h1>
  <article id="muchamasmierda">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus eveniet iusto sapiente, autem voluptates dolores, necessitatibus pariatur a asperiores consectetur, porro esse omnis hic ut deleniti dolor labore tenetur molestiae.</p>
  </article>
  <figure id="masmierda">
   <h2>HABITACIONES</h2>
   <img class="fachada" src="Fachada-Oscuro-MD.png" alt="">

  </figure>
  
  <article>

   <figure id="jodo">
    <img  src="2camas-1.jpg" alt="">
   </figure>

   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid assumenda repellat velit laborum, accusamus debitis et, officia voluptatibus fugiat est eius deleniti amet minus soluta beatae unde nam, laboriosam repellendus.</p>
  </article>

 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: INSERTO UNA CAPTURA DE PANTALLA QUE MUESTRA EL PROBLEMA]

Comment: Para añadir imágenes puedes usar https://placeholder.com/

Comment: En el ejemplo que nos pasas se puede cambiar perfectamente el tamaño de los **h1**. Lo único que en los **CSS** tienes una regla que afecta a los **h1** y les das un **top: -20px**, por lo que el que tienes con texto "POSADA" se sale por arriba de la pantalla y no se ve apenas.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda en cuanto a las imágenes ya pude cambiar el codigo. y es cierto PHPMyguel  en el código que os paso el h1 sale fuera de la pantalla debido al top: -20px; pero es una regla necesaria que tuve que poner por la imágen que tengo puesta, en mi codigo se ve el texto. Lo más extraño es que aqui si cambia el tamaño del h1 pero en mi código no se cambia.. esto es más extraño que antes.

Comment: Entonces debes tener algún estilo que sobreescriba el tamaño que intentas ponerle. ¿Has probado con un selector más específico o con `!important`?

Comment: Con el seelctor !important si que me cambia el tamaño, ahora mi trabajo tendrá que centrarse en ver que estilo sobreescribe el tamaño que quiero ponerle al h1. Por que no veo nada que pueda sobreescribirlo. Los código estan copiados tal cual de Sublime Text.

Comment: Puedes hacer un <h1 class="miH1">POSADA</H1> y creas en la hoja de estilos un .miH1{font-size: 1rem;}; podria ser un ejemplo.

Comment: Si inspeccionas el **h1** desde el navegador con **botón derecho del ratón -> inspeccionar** puedes ver las reglas **CSS** que están afectando al elemento. Ahí podrás ver que regla está afectando también al **font-size**.